How to use rgbmatrix and rpi-rf repos
My project is a LED matrix scoreboard. I've got a Raspberry Pi Zero W and an Adafruit RGB Matrix Bonnet.
I'd like to use an MX-RM-5V receiver and 2 radio buttons to change the home and away scores and for this I need to use rpi-rf repository.
The problem is that no matter how I'm trying to write the codes, inside the scoreboard or in subprocess, I'm unable to use another GPIO pins. I tried a few unused pins but got the same messages:
admin@scoreboard:~/Scoreboard/Subprocess $ sudo python3 test2.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/admin/Scoreboard/Subprocess/test2.py", line 43, in <module>
rfdevice.enable_rx()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/rpi_rf/rpi_rf.py", line 189, in enable_rx
GPIO.add_event_detect(self.gpio, GPIO.BOTH)
RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection

So how it is possible to use the free GPIO pins?

This appears to be similar to a problem discussed in this stackoverflow.com question. The solution was to remove the current gpio libraries and install newer lgpio libraries. Specifically:
sudo apt remove python3-rpi.gpio
sudo apt install python3-rpi-lgpio

From the rpi-lgpio web site:

rpi-lgpio is a compatibility package intended to provide compatibility
with the rpi-gpio (aka RPi.GPIO) library, on top of kernels that only
support the gpiochip device (and which have removed the deprecated
sysfs GPIO interface).

